# Dereferencing a pointer to 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I don't understand why when dereferencing a pointer to an array, the result is the address of the first value of the array

```
int array[2][2] = {{0,1},{0,1}}; 
int (*p)[2];
p = array;
```

```
p = address of a[0][0], p+1 = address of a[1][0], 
*p = address of a[0][0], (*p)+1 = the address of a[0][1];
```

I understand that p is a pointer to an array of 2 integers, not a pointer to an integer. But if we print out the value of p, it's still the address of an integer. I want to know what's going on under the hood? Is p a pointer to an array of pointers? So we have to dereference it twice to get the value of the integer its pointing?

A pointer to an int,

```
int* p;
```

is a variable, stored in a location, that contains the address of another variable (int).

When we dereference it, we get the value of that variable. How does this process work exactly with a pointer to an array?

Comment: What do your warnings say about the assignment from incompatible pointer types with `p = array;`? `int (*p)[2];` would be proper.

Comment: ok I just corrected it

Comment: There are two things you need to remember when it comes to arrays and their relationship with pointers. The first is that the array on itself decays to a pointer to its first element. Which means `array` is exactly the same as `&array[0]`. The second thing is that for any array *or pointer* `array` and index `i`, the expression `array[i]` is exactly equal to `*(array + i)`.

Comment: A 2D array is an *Array of 1D arrays*. `p` points to the first 1D array in `array`. So `p` points to `array[0]` and `p+1` points to `array[1]`. Recall on access an array is converted to a pointer to its first element. So `*p` will point to the first element of the first row (it is the same as `*(p+0)` which is the same as `p[0]`)

Comment: And when dealing with arrays and pointers, I really recommend that you draw them out on paper. Use squares for single variables, rectangles for arrays (divide to show elements), and arrows for pointers. It usually help getting an overview of things.

Comment: `p = address of a[0][0]` That should be the address of `a[0]` instead (yes, the address is the same, but the type is different). `p+1 = address of a[1][0]` That should be the address of `a[1]` instead. `*(p+1) = the address of a[0][1]` No, that contradicts what you just wrote above.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry made a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The address of an array is the same as the address of its first element.

Given the definition `int array[2][2] = {{0,1},{0,1}};`, the compiler arranges some location in memory to contain the `int` values 0, 1, 0, and 1. Let’s say that location has address 1000, and the `int` value 0 is stored in bytes 1000-1003, 1 is stored in 1004 to 1007, 0 is stored in 1008 to 1011, and 1 is stored in 1012 to 1015.

Where does the element `array[0][0]` start in memory? At location 1000.

Where does the array `array` start in memory? At location 1000.

Where does the array `array[0]` start in memory? At location 1000.

The array starts in memory at the same location its first element starts in memory. Also, `array[0]`, which is itself an array, starts at the location 1000.

So, after `p = array;`, `p` points the location 1000. And the element `array[0][0]` also starts at location 1000. So, when you print `p`, as with `printf("%p\n", (void *) p);`, it is unsurprising you get the same result as when you print the address of `array[0][0]`, as with `printf("%p\n", (void *) &array[0][0]);`.

### An array is automatically converted to the address of its first element.

Next, let’s consider `*p`. The type of `p` is `int (*)[2]`, a pointer to an array of 2 `int`. Therefore, `*p` is an array of 2 `int`.

In particular, `*p` is an array. Suppose we attempt to print it by passing it as an argument to `printf`. What happens?

In C, when an array is used in an expression, it is automatically converted to the address of its first element (except when the array is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array). So, if you use `*p` as an argument to `printf`, it initially means `array[0]`, but that array is converted to the address of its first argument. So passing `*p` as an argument actually passes `&array[0][0]` (or, equivalently `&(*p)[0]`).

Thus, `printf("%p\n", (void *) *p);` will print the same address as `printf("%p\n", (void *) &a[0][0]);`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Value at an array can be accessed using
   `array[i] = *(array+i)` (expansion of `[i]`).
2. Similarily, `(*p)[i] = *(*(p+i))`. So, we need to dereference twice to access the value.
3. If you want to access, `array[0][0]`, you have to use `*(*(p+0)+0) = **p;`,
   Similarily, `array[0][1]` can be accessed using `*(*(p+0)+1) = *((*p)+1);`
4. Note, `*p` points to first row (stores address of `array[0][0]`),  and `*(p+1)` points to second row (stores address of `array[1][0]`).

Please check the below code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    int(*p)[2];
    p = array;


    printf("The address of array[0][0] is %p \n",&array[0][0]);
    printf("The address of *p is %p \n",*p);

    printf("The address of array[1][0] is %p \n",&array[1][0]);
    printf("The address of *(p+1) is %p \n",*(p+1));

    printf("The value of array[0][0] is %d \n",array[0][0]);
    printf("The value of **p is %d \n",**p);

    printf("The value of array[0][1] is %d \n",array[0][1]);
    printf("The value of *((*p)+1) is %d \n",*((*p)+1));


    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
The address of array[0][0] is 0x7fff6e8781a0 
The address of *p is 0x7fff6e8781a0 
The address of array[1][0] is 0x7fff6e8781a8 
The address of *(p+1) is 0x7fff6e8781a8 
The value of array[0][0] is 1 
The value of **p is 1 
The value of array[0][1] is 2 
The value of *((*p)+1) is 2
```